# Accessing items on the page created via APEX_ITEM.SELECT_LIST

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have an item on the page created via APEX_ITEM.SELECT_LIST. The item's name property is `f02`. I have a dynamic action one page load where I want to check in Client-side condition what is the selected value of that item.

I tried setting the type to `Item=Value`, then setting Item to `f02` and Value propertyto `Test`. When I run the page I do not get any errors but the condition resolved to False even though the value selected in the select list is `Test`.

I tried changing `f02` to apex.item('f02') but it made no difference.

What is the correct way to access that type of a field?

Comment: If you open the browser debugging window and type `$("select[name='f02'"]).val()`, what do you get?

Comment: Don't let the package name confuse you, `APEX_ITEM` does not actually add declarative APEX items to your page. It merely generates HTML for your web page.

Answer (score 1):

```
APEX_ITEM.SELECT_LIST(
    p_idx           IN   NUMBER,
    p_value         IN   VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
    p_list_values   IN   VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
    p_attributes    IN   VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
    p_show_null     IN   VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'NO',
    p_null_value    IN   VARCHAR2 DEFAULT '%NULL%',
    p_null_text     IN   VARCHAR2 DEFAULT '%',
    p_item_id       IN   VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
    p_item_label    IN   VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
    p_show_extra    IN   VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'YES')
    RETURN VARCHAR2;
```

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14373_01/apirefs.32/e13369/apex_item.htm#AEAPI205

---

If the value of p_item_id is defined you can use in client side condition the option javascript expression.

```
$('#ITEM_ID').val() == something
```

or

```
apex.jQuery('#ITEM_ID').val() == something
```

You can try get the value with apex.item('ITEM_ID').getValue()... but i'm not sure if it works.

Comment: Not sure if we are on the same page. I do have both p_idx and p_item_id set but I doubt I can use JQuery in a Client-Side condition section of the Dynamic Action

Comment: On server side condition it's not possible. But in client side condition you can use jquery.

Comment: How should I do it?

On Client-side Condition I have 3 fields:

Type: Item=Value

Item: 

Value: Test

What do i put in for Item?

Comment: On type, you need to choose "javascript expression"